# How to release resource in canceled CompletableFuture

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, try-with-resources

### Uscase

Suppose we run execution with CompletableFuture.runAsync(..) and in runnable we have try-with-resources block (we are using some resource that should be closed whatever happens), and at some point when execution is not finished in try block we cancel the completable future... altough execution is stopped the resource that should be closed is not closed the close() of AutoClosable is not called...

---

### Question

Is that a java issue or there is a way to do that properly? without hacky workarounds like using futures (that support interruption etc..), and if its expected behaviour how should one handle similar situation when non interruptable CompletableFuture is canceled...?

---

### The Code

```
public class AutoClosableResourceTest {

    public static class SomeService{
        public void connect(){
            System.out.println("connect");
        }

        public Integer disconnect(){
            System.out.println("disconnect");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class AutoClosableResource<T> implements AutoCloseable {

        private final T resource;
        private final Runnable closeFunction;

        private AutoClosableResource(T resource, Runnable closeFunction){
            this.resource = resource;
            this.closeFunction = closeFunction;
        }

        public T get(){
            return resource;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws Exception {
            closeFunction.run();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testTryWithResource() throws InterruptedException {
        SomeService service  = new SomeService();

        CompletableFuture<Void> async = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try (AutoClosableResource<SomeService> resource = new AutoClosableResource<>(service, service::disconnect)) {
                resource.get().connect();
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("working...");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Thread.sleep(2500);
        async.cancel(true);
        Thread.sleep(2500);

    }
}
```

this will produce

```
connect
working...
working...
working...
working...
```

as you can see it does not call cancel() and leaves resource opened...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you have difficulties in understanding what the purpose of `CompletableFuture` is. Have a look at the first sentence of [its class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html):

> A `Future` that may be explicitly completed (setting its value and status), …

So unlike `FutureTask` which is completed by the thread executing its `run` method, a `CompletableFuture` can be completed by any thread which will set its value/status at an arbitrary point of time. The `CompletableFuture` doesn’t know which thread will complete it and it doesn’t even know whether there is a thread currently working on its completion.

Therefore the `CompletableFuture` can not interrupt the right thread when being canceled. That’s a fundamental part of its design.

If you want a worker thread that you can interrupt you are better off using `FutureTask`/`ThreadPoolExecutor`. The task scheduled that way may still complete a `CompletableFuture` at its end.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will be stuck in an infinite loop.  Calling async.cancel will not communicate with the following loop its desire to stop.

```
while (true) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("working...");
}
```

The test case exits because the thread stuck in this loop is not a daemon thread.

Replace the while loop check with the following, which checks the isCancelled flag on each iteration.  Calling CompletableFuture.cancel() will mark the future as cancelled, but it does not interrupt the thread that was started via runAsync.

```
while (isCancelled()) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
   System.out.println("working...");
}
```

Comment: How do you access the CompletableFuture from within Executor/Thread/Runnable/Callable/FutureTask so you can signal the task as Completed/Cancelled, or check if isCancelled? I mean, you are calling isCancelled fro mthe computation loop, which it means you are asuming the computation loop is wrapped in a CompletableFuture child. I don't understand sorry

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "complete" method of the CompletableFuture to stop the thread.

Below a simple code to show the behaviour:

```
package com.ardevco;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class CompletableFutureTest3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

     ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

     CompletableFuture<Integer> longRunningcompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i--) {
           System.out.println("i " + i);
           sleep();
        }
        return 1; // we will newer reach this line so the thread will be stuck
     });

     CompletableFuture<Integer> completor = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("completing the longRunningcompletableFuture");
        longRunningcompletableFuture.complete(1000);
        System.out.println("completed the longRunningcompletableFuture");
        return 10;
     });

     Thread.sleep(10000);

     System.out.println("completor...");
     int i = completor.get();
     System.out.println("completor i:" + i);
     System.out.println("completor...");

     System.out.println("completableFutureToBeCompleted2...");
     int i2 = longRunningcompletableFuture.get();
     System.out.println("completableFutureToBeCompleted2: " + i2);
     System.out.println("completableFutureToBeCompleted2...");

  }

  private static void sleep() {
     try {Thread.sleep(1000);}catch (Exception e) {}
  }
```

}

output:

i 0
completing the longRunningcompletableFuture
completed the longRunningcompletableFuture
i -1
i -2
i -3
i -4
i -5
i -6
i -7
i -8
i -9
i -10
completor...
completor i:10
completor...
completableFutureToBeCompleted2...
completableFutureToBeCompleted2: 1000
completableFutureToBeCompleted2...

Answer (score 0):

Though there is an answer marked as correct, the reason is quite different - please see documentation for `CompletableFuture.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean-) and read the article [CompletableFuture can't be interrupted](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2015/03/completablefuture-cant-be-interrupted.html) to understand the problem better.

This issue is addressed in my [Tascalate Concurrent](https://github.com/vsilaev/tascalate-concurrent) library, the changes to your code should be:
From

`CompletableFuture<Void> async = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
...
});`

To

`Promise<Void> async = CompletableTask.runAsync(() -> {
...
}, someExplicitExecutor);`

...and you will get expected behavior (executor thread is interrupted, AutoClosable is closed, `async` is completed with `CancellationException`).

You can read more about the library in [my blog](https://vsilaev.com/2017/07/29/announcing-tascalate-concurrent/)

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem in Java 8 SE. For me, it's important not to use third-party libraries.

> cancel(**mayInterruptIfRunning**) this value has no effect in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing.

The **idea** is to use *Thread.interrupt()* when calling *cancel()*, but only for **Runnable**.

```
/** Enable and disable the interrupt */
private static class Interruptor {

    volatile boolean interrupted;
    volatile Runnable interrupt;

    /** Enable interrupt support */
    synchronized boolean start() {
        if (interrupted) {
            return false;
        }
        Thread runThread = Thread.currentThread();
        interrupt = () -> {
            if (runThread != Thread.currentThread()) {
                runThread.interrupt();
            }
        };
        return true;
    }

    /** Interrupt Runnable */
    synchronized void interrupt() {
        if (interrupted) {
            return;
        }
        interrupted = true;
        if (interrupt != null) {
            interrupt.run();
            interrupt = null;
        }
    }

    /** Disable interrupt support */
    synchronized void finish() {
        interrupt = null;
    }
}


/** CompletableFuture with interrupt support */
public static CompletableFuture<Void> runAsyncInterrupted(Runnable run) {

    final Interruptor interruptor = new Interruptor();

    Runnable wrap = () -> {
        if (!interruptor.start()) { // allow interruption
            return; // was canceled before the thread started
        }
        try {
            run.run(); // can be interrupted
        } finally {
            interruptor.finish(); // can no longer be interrupted
        }
    };

    CompletableFuture<Void> cfRun = CompletableFuture.runAsync(wrap);

    // here is caught "CompletableFuture.cancel()"
    cfRun.whenComplete((r, t) -> {
        if (t instanceof CancellationException) {
            interruptor.interrupt();
        }
    });

    return cfRun;
}
```

***Example of use***

```
Runnable mySlowIoRun = () -> {
    try {
        InputStream is = openSomeResource(); // open resource
        try {
            // there may be problem (#1) with reading,
            // such as loss of network connection
            int bt = is.read();
            // ..
            // .. some code
        } finally {
            is.close(); // problem (#2): releases any system resources associated with the stream
        }
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        throw new RuntimeException(th);
    }
};

CompletableFuture<Void> cf = runAsyncInterrupted(mySlowIoRun);

try {
    cf.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // 5 sec timeout
} catch (Throwable th) {
    cf.cancel(true); // cancel with interrupt mySlowIoRun
    throw th;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is a generalization of how I typically handle the problem.. pass-in a cancellable state, and close resources IMMEDIATELY after the open state.

```
private static BufferedReader openFile(String fn) {
    try {
        return Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fn));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

static class Util {
    static void closeQuietly(AutoCloseable c) {
        if (c == null) return;
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    static <T extends AutoCloseable, R> R runThenCloseQuietly(T c, Function<T,R> cb) {
        try {
            return cb.apply(c);
        } finally {
            closeQuietly(c);
        }
    }

    static <T extends AutoCloseable, R> Optional<R> runThenCloseQuietlyCancellable(BooleanSupplier cancelled
        , T c, Function<T,Optional<R>> cb) {
        if (c == null) return Optional.empty(); // safe doesn't throw
        try {
            if (cancelled.getAsBoolean()) return Optional.empty(); // might throw, wrap for safety
            return cb.apply(c); // might throw
        } finally {
            closeQuietly(c); // might throw, but at least we're closed
        }
    }

    private static Optional<String> emptyString() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

interface Cancellable {
    boolean isCancelled();
    void cancel();
}

static class CancellableAB implements Cancellable {
    private final AtomicBoolean cancelled;

    CancellableAB(AtomicBoolean cancelled) {
        this.cancelled = cancelled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return cancelled.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        cancelled.set(true);
    }
}
static class CancellableArray implements Cancellable {
    private final boolean[] cancelled;
    private final int idx;
    CancellableArray(boolean[] cancelled) {
        this(cancelled, 0);
    }
    CancellableArray(boolean[] cancelled, int idx) {
        this.cancelled = cancelled;
        this.idx = idx;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return cancelled[idx];
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        cancelled[idx]=true;
    }
}

static class CancellableV implements Cancellable {
    volatile boolean cancelled;

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return cancelled;
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        this.cancelled = true;
    }
}

/**
 * The only reason this is a class is because we need SOME external object for the lambda to check for mutated
 * cancelled state.
 * This gives the added benefit that we can directly call cancel on the resource.
 * We allow a cancellable to be passed in to CHAIN-IN cancellable state.  e.g. if cancellation should affect MULTIPLE
 * CompletableFuture states, we don't want other promises to tie references to this task.. So the cancellable
 * object can be externalized.
 * 
 * Normally you don't need this much genericism, you can directly implement a volatile 'cancel boolean'.
 * But this allows you to create a C.F. task as a 3rd party library call - gives maximum flexibility to invoker.
 *
 */
static class FooTask {
    volatile Cancellable cancelled;
    String fileName;

    public FooTask(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.cancelled = new CancellableV();
    }

    public FooTask(String fileName, Cancellable cancelled) {
        this.cancelled = cancelled;
    }


    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return cancelled.isCancelled();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        cancelled.cancel();
    }

    /**
     * asynchronously opens file, scans for first valid line (closes file), then processes the line.
     * Note if an exception happens, it's the same as not finding any lines. Don't need to special case.
     * Use of utility functions is mostly for generic-mapping
     * (avoiding annoying double-type-casting plus editor warnings)
     */
    CompletableFuture<Optional<Long>> run1() {
        return
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> openFile(fileName))
                .thenApplyAsync(c ->  { // this stage MUST close the prior stage
                        if(cancelled.isCancelled() || c == null) return Util.emptyString(); // shouldn't throw
                        try {
                            return c
                                .lines()
                                .filter(line -> !cancelled.isCancelled())
                                .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#"))
                                .findFirst();
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                            Util.closeQuietly(c);
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                )
                .thenApplyAsync(oLine -> // this stage doesn't need closing
                    oLine
                        .map(line -> line.split(":"))
                        .map(cols -> cols[2])
                        .map(Long::valueOf)
                        )
            ;
    }


    /**
     * Same as run1 but avoids messy brackets + try-finally
     */
    CompletableFuture<Optional<Long>> run2() {
        return
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> openFile(fileName))
                .thenApplyAsync(c ->  // this stage MUST close the prior stage
                    Util.runThenCloseQuietly(
                        c
                        , r -> cancelled.isCancelled() ? Util.emptyString() // shouldn't throw
                            : r
                            .lines()
                            .filter(line -> !cancelled.isCancelled())
                            .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#"))
                            .findFirst()
                    ))
                .thenApplyAsync(oLine -> // this stage doesn't need closing
                    oLine
                        .map(line -> line.split(":"))
                        .map(cols -> cols[2])
                        .map(Long::valueOf)
                        )
            ;
    }

    /**
     * Same as run2 but avoids needing the teneary operator - says Cancellable in func-name so is more readable
     */
    CompletableFuture<Optional<Long>> run3() {
        return
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> openFile(fileName))
                .thenApplyAsync(c ->  // this stage MUST close the prior stage
                    Util.runThenCloseQuietlyCancellable(
                    cancelled::isCancelled // lambda here is slightly easier to read than explicit if-statement
                    , c
                    , r ->  r
                            .lines()
                            .filter(line -> !cancelled.isCancelled())
                            .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#"))
                            .findFirst()
                ))
                .thenApplyAsync(oLine -> // this stage doesn't need closing
                    oLine
                        .map(line -> line.split(":"))
                        .map(cols -> cols[2])
                        .map(Long::valueOf)
                        )
        ;
    }

}

@Test
public void testFooGood() {
    var task = new FooTask("/etc/passwd");
    var cf = task.run3();

    var oVal = cf.join();
    assertTrue(oVal.isPresent());
    System.out.println(oVal.get()); // should not throw
}

@Test
public void testFooCancel() {
    var task = new FooTask("/etc/passwd");
    var cf = task.run3();
    task.cancel();

    var oVal = cf.join();
    assertTrue(oVal.isEmpty());
}
```